# SSL handshake failure Websphere 1 of 2 servers

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere

### Setup :

- 2 websphere servers (8.5 fixpack 13), both (at first look) the same config.
- 1 application (ear with 2 wars)

### Problem :

SSL handshake fails for 1 of the 2 servers.
I enabled the logging for debugging SSL and came out the following difference between the servers :

**Good server** :

> [12/18/18 8:08:52:466 CET] 0000017d SystemOut     O Client write key:
>   [12/18/18 8:08:52:466 CET] 0000017d SystemOut     O 0000: 3d 82 67 06
>   09 d0 a8 93  01 8f 42 93 e3 24 6d c0  ..g.......B...m. **0010: 76 cb 4a
>   7f b9 a7 3e 61  c7 ac ca 60 08 77 a5 a0  v.J....a.....w..**
>
> [12/18/18 8:08:52:466 CET] 0000017d SystemOut     O Server write key:
>   [12/18/18 8:08:52:466 CET] 0000017d SystemOut     O 0000: ad d4 83 5c b2 6f e8 ad  a5 7e 5d 50 39 04 78 74  .....o.....P9.xt **0010: f7 7f 2d
>   73 c7 1f aa f0  5c 72 ac ce a5 cc 76 21  ...s.....r....v.**

**Bad server** :

> [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O Client write
>   key:
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O 0000: 2f
>   67 20 ee 13 d6 22 03  d6 aa bc 78 ca bf a9 0a  .g.........x....
>
> [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O Server write
>   key:
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O 0000: fc
>   64 13 e2 98 00 af cc  10 ae 34 80 fb 2c ab 5d  .d........4.....
>
> [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O ... no IV derived
>   for this protocol
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:817 CET] 0000013d SystemOut
>   O JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA512withRSA from provider TBD via init
>   
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:818 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O Signatures: 
>   Using signature RSA from provider from initSignIBMJCE version 1.8
>   [12/18/18 8:08:51:821 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O 
>   CertificateVerify
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:821 CET] 0000013d SystemOut
>   O Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:822 CET]
>   0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTls12Prf from
>   provider TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:822 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O HandshakeMessage:  TLS Keygenerator IbmTlsPrf  from
>   provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:822 CET]
>   0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake,
>   length = 136
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:822 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O
>   WebContainer : 0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
>   [12/18/18 8:08:51:822 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using
>   cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:51:822 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O CipherBox:  Using cipher
>   AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
>   [12/18/18 8:08:51:823 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using
>   MAC HmacSHA1 from provider TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:823
>   CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O MAC:  Using MessageDigest HmacSHA1 from
>   provider IBMJCE version 1.8
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:823 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O  Finished
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:823 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O verify_data:  { 150, 40, 219, 56, 139, 255, 165, 51,
>   71, 246, 110, 176 }
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:824 CET] 0000013d SystemOut
>   O 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:824 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O
>   WebContainer : 0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 64
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:51:876 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, READ:
>   TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:876 CET]
>   0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from
>   provider TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:876 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O CipherBox:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from
>   provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:876 CET]
>   0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using MAC HmacSHA1 from provider
>   TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:877 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O
>   MAC:  Using MessageDigest HmacSHA1 from provider IBMJCE version
>   1.8
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:877 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 64
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:51:877 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O  Finished
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:51:877 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O verify_data:  { 217, 179,
>   178, 151, 190, 135, 169, 219, 85, 206, 55, 194 }
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:51:878 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:878
>   CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTls12Prf
>   from provider TBD via init 
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:878 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O HandshakeMessage:  TLS Keygenerator IbmTlsPrf  from
>   provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:878 CET]
>   0000013d SystemOut     O %% Cached client session: [Session-129,
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:895 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data,
>   length = 336
>  [12/18/18 8:08:51:895 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O
>   WebContainer : 0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 5984
>   [12/18/18 8:08:52:053 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0,
>   READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 1008
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:52:054 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, called
>   close()
>  [12/18/18 8:08:52:054 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O
>   WebContainer : 0, called closeInternal(true)
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:52:054 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, SEND
>   TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
>  [12/18/18
>   8:08:52:054 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, WRITE:
>   TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 48
>  [12/18/18 8:08:52:054 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, called closeSocket(true)
>   [12/18/18 8:08:52:603 CET] 0000013d SystemOut     O SSLv3 protocol was
>   requested but was not enabled
>  [12/18/18 8:08:52:604 CET] 0000013d
>   SystemOut     O

As I marked in the good server, I see in the client and server write key a part 0010, what is not in the bad server.
I assume because it's not there the SSL handshake fails what results in failed call.

We use a lot of web services, we have problem only in 2 endpoints and the other endpoints are working well on both the servers.

If someone could point me to the direction on where to search, I'll be very thankful.

### Edit :

- Tried adding :  `-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true` as startup param but didn't help.

Comment: "SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled" doesn't it mean that the client tries to request for SSLv3 bur support for this on the server side is disabled?  (SSLv3 was deprecated long time ago)

Comment: can you try to reach the service using curl with -vvv option? I find curl log more redable `Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [89 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):

...
`

Comment: @IrekL. Thx for the comment, the SSLv3 was indeed requested by the client but we don't use SSLv3 because it's unsafe. We found the problem and I added it also in the topic.

Comment: Suggest you add the solution as an "Answer" here, and accept it.

Comment: @dbreaux done, can only accept it in 16Hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like security on the bad server was configured with standard in stead of the more secure US version :

- JDK/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
- JDK/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar

You can find more explication in [this Dzone article.](https://dzone.com/articles/install-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited)